# My Final Song to Riley

Tags: riddle, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, poetry

*Entry into [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #38: Reusing Information 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/fortnightly-topic-challenge-38-reusing-information-1)*

<sub>This will also be my final Riley Riddle for a week or two because it is arriving near the end of the term and school is expecting some assessments...</sub>

---

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My prefix **i**s **q**uick with but one ant alone, 
>  Though it may start to slow down with all.*
>
> *My suffix, a**b**ove, has an a**l**pha to own, 
>  Though it will not head far with the fall.*
>
> *My **in**fix might yell with a notable **to**ne, 
>  Though re**me**mber not p**et**s in its call.*
>
> *As home to the third or a tool for a bone, 
>  I will sing with the wind in a class to enthral!*
>
> ***What am I?***

The bold letters in each paragraph give a clue to what the next paragraph is referring to, and all in the same way; the other clues are also similarly set out, even with multiple meanings, e.g.

> "Yell" also refers to **yellow** and "sing" sounds like **string**.

The title is also a clue, but only has one clue in it; one clue for one song's title. 
 Altogether, this riddle reuses information!

---

**Hint 1:**

> "Notable" also refers to **notes** and "class" sounds like **brass**.

**Hint 2:**

> "Down" also refers to **download** and "alpha" sounds like **far**.

**Hint 3:**

> **iq** = **IQ**.

**Hint 4:**

> **bl** = **bell**.

Comment: Damn, no one's answering. I guess this riddle is too hard. Have u considered putting a bounty on this?

Comment: @KevinL oh woops. I forgot about this, with all the anagrams I've been doing. I will just keep adding hints and putting a bounty. I'll do $50$, and if nobody answers,I'll go to $100$. Some user should answer by then... but if they don't, I'll just keep doubling. Thanks for letting me know :P

Comment: No problem mate :D

Comment: Are you looking for a song name? The answer is still a single word yes?

Comment: @Dorrulf yes, and it is not a song name ;)

Comment: @user477343 would you start another bounty on this nice question?

Answer (score 7):

I think I can finally see what the solution is here:

> **INSTRUMENT**

*My prefix **i**s **q**uick with but one ant alone,*
*Though it may start to slow down with all.*

> The prefix is **INST**. INST+ANT=INSTANT, with connotations of something being 'quick' ('in an instant'). However, INST+ALL=INSTALL, and an installation (e.g. a software *down*load) may be a slower process.

*My suffix, a**b**ove, has an a**l**pha to own,*
*Though it will not head far with the fall.*

> Bearing in mind the 'iq' reuse from the prefix clue, the suffix is **MENT**. Because if we place 'MENT' *above*/before 'ALPHA' and let *fall* (i.e. remove) 'PHA' (as a soundalike for 'far'), we get MENT+AL(-pha)=MENTAL, which has connections to 'IQ' and the *head*.

*My **in**fix might yell with a notable **to**ne,*
*Though re**me**mber not p**et**s in its call.*

> The infix is **TRUM**, because a TRUMPET *might yell with a notable tone* but we have to 'forget' (i.e. remove) 'PET'. The 'bl' from the suffix clue, when pronounced 'b-ell', connects with the *bell* of a trumpet, which is the name of the part where the sound comes out.

*As home to the third or a tool for a bone,*
*I will sing with the wind in a class to enthral!*

> 'into' and 'meet' from the infix clue purely signify that we need to put the parts together *into* one in order to *meet* the solution, which is INST+TRUM+MENT=**INSTRUMENT**.
>
>  A trumpet (our *third* clue above) *is* a musical instrument (as is a trom*bone*), and instrument is also a synonym of '*tool*'. The final line has connotations of playing music, possibly in an orchestra (*sing*, [wood]*wind*, *class*[ical]), as does the mention of 'song' in the title itself.

Phew, we got there in the end! Note, of course, that there may be further hidden 'information reuses' by the OP here, given the Fortnightly Topic Challenge theme when it was set (for example, they state in the question itself that 'notable' sounds like 'notes' - another connection to the theme - and that 'yell' conjures up the idea of 'yellow', the colour of the item used in the infix clue), but I hope you agree that my answer here has dug up a sufficient amount as to have led us to a satisfying answer at last!

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:

My suffix, above, has an alpha to own,

> has an 'L' far to 'O'?

Not sure...

@user477343 pls comment, thanks!

Comment: No, that's not it.... but you are kind of on the right track. I might have to give the prefix away for users to get the idea. I'll do that in a hint. Apologies for not commenting earlier!