# My Actual Final Song to Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

Okay, *this* is my final Riley Riddle (and not my [previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72014/my-final-song-to-riley) one), because I could not resist... 
 ...and that meant this had to be even better.

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My prefix will pray with an S, 
>  My suffix is red with an A, 
>  My infix, so ill with an F, 
> If only affixed with an E. 
>  
>  Because the answer is SAFE.*

---

**Note:**

> The answer is **not** "safe / SAFE". This is genuinely true; no wordplay involved. 
>  And although the answer is safe... it can likely be the result of crime.

**Hint 1:**

> Although the verses do not rhyme, 
>  I tell you this is not a crime. 
>  Well, now it rhymes, but see not that! 
>  A word at end, you should look at. 
>  
>  Now changing how you say this word, 
>  Will highlight even when absurd; 
>  Though then you might add properly, 
>  To find the sharing property.

**Hint 2:**

> The three main parts I have described, 
>  Have two such elements inscribed. 
>  The first is in the prior hint; 
>  The second is the fingerprint. 
>  
>  Now every word has much intent: 
>  To rhyme and secretly present. 
>  For instance, I used "prior", why? 
>  It punished the unjustified.

**Major Hint:**

> I used the word "**affix**ed" for a reason. E needs to be added to each **affix**; e.g., 
>  
>  There exists a word that contains an E and is **fre**quently used to **spray**. 
>  Because this word is the Prefix + E, take E out and continue in that way. 
>  
>  The answer might **just** come to mind if **injuries** are what you find.

---

Any edits that I make will either be hints or grammatical improvements. Also added the `knowledge` tag for the second hint (though very little knowledge is required).

I would also like to point out that *nearly every word is used with an alternative purpose as opposed to making things rhyme*. This is to say, they each have clues; e.g., **fre** could refer to **fire**.

Comment: Lol, nice riddle (+1). When will u probably be back?

Comment: @KevinL thank you! I will try to be active as much as I can, but I won't have time to make puzzles and/or riddles. I have heaps of school stuff and will start getting back *on track* (sorry for the pun, hahah) by about September $22$nd :P

Comment: Will be looking forward to your next riddle then :D

Comment: I can only think of the infix being rot13(syh) but can't think of a word with it that fits the riddle :p.

Comment: @mrdeadsven that is not it. Think differently. Would you like me to give a hint for that in particular? :P

Comment: nah, want to figure it out myself. and if you say think differently I started it with thinking like this rot13(cenl jvgu F = FCENL erq jvgu N = ERNQ vyy jvgu S = SVYY.) and then I would have to do something with that, but I think this is way to far fetched :p.

Comment: @mrdeadsven that's not far-fetched. You got it! Keep going!! xD Use the hint for that extra bit of progress, I suggest :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer

My prefix will pray with an S,

> SPRAY

My infix, so ill with an F,

> FILL

My suffix is red with an A,

> not sure I guess READ

If only affixed with an E.

> you can connect the words with each other by putting an 'E' in between fill and read for sprayfillEread. This is also why I think read is wrong because sprayfiller seems like a correct word but I have no idea what to put behind it because the letters EAD are still not used if the word has sprayfiller to start.

Throwing this one out here so maybe someone else gets an idea out of it :p.

EDIT considering the extra info I got:

It might have something to do with

> a robbery of a bank.

Because

> it has to do with a crime, in a bank they can rob the SAFE and if they get caught they are in quite the fix (fix used as in an awkward situation).

Final Answer:

> HOSPITAL

PREFIX

> HOS of HOSE to SPRAY

INFIX

> PI of PIE that FILLS you up

SUFFIX

> TAL of TALE that you read

Comment: The last part is incorrect, though everything else is. I will say but one thing: there is a reason why I used the word **affixed**. Think of the word and a "sharing property" somehow associated with the "end". Sometimes, crimes have to do with my answer, even though it is quite safe :P

Comment: @user477343 I thought it was wordplay to reference to rot13(N SVK orpnhfr lbh hfr n fcenl svyyre gb svk fbzrguvat hc) :p. but I'll keep it in mind when looking for the answer

Comment: No, but close. You are looking in the right area. There is not just one kind of fix, is there? :D

Comment: @user477343 made an edit to my answer (just a speculation) on the extra info you gave.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I'm finishing my WW1 assignment for school). That is not the answer, but is quite a great speculation, to be honest; I don't blame you for thinking that. (ROT13) Gur grez "nssvkrq" ersref gb gur "nssvkrf" (qvssrerag xvaqf bs "svkrf", v.r. gur cersvk; vasvk; naq fhssvk) va gur evqqyr. Guvf zrnaf gung gur cersvk naq vasvk naq fhssvk zhfg rnpu unir na R nqqrq gb gurz gb qb gur npgvbaf (r.t. cenl jvgu na F). Guvf vf n znwbe uvag!

Comment: @user477343 no worries only reason I'm fast at answering today is because I have to wait for someone to fix something so I can start working again otherwise I also take a long time :p. Anyway this is what I was thinking first but I kinda got stuck there so I went to look at it in another way, but I'm going to keep trying until I (or someone else :p) finds it.

Comment: @user477343 based on the new tips I'm going to make another guess might the word be rot13(nzohynapr orpnhfr nzohynaprf ner fbzrgvzrf ba pevzrfprarf. gurl ner fnsr orpnhfr gurl ner gurer gb uryc lbh naq nyfb lbhe ynfg uvag gung vg pbzrf gb zvaq jvgu vawhevrf. Ohg V unirag sbhaq gur cersvkrf sbe gurz bayl OH nf vasvk sbe ohpxrg gb svyy fbzrguvat.)

Comment: That is so close. It definitely relates to an Rot13(nzohynapr). In fact... it *very* much relates to nzohynaprf :D

Comment: Last guess of today :p rot13(Rzretrapl Iruvphyr Yvtugf, gurl pna or sebz n cbyvprpne sbe gur pevzr cneg ohg vg qbrfag unir gb or (nzohynapr) naq znlor gur vaqvpngbe va gur evqqyr lbh arrq yvtug gb ernq vg vf erq (gur yvtugf ner erq) gur yvtugf synfu (fcenl vf qvfgevohgvat gur yvtugf) whfg abg fher sbe gur svyy cneg.)

Comment: No, that is not it, but this hint is gonna give it away: (ROT13) Gur nafjre vf abg nobhg gur nzohynapr... vg'f nobhg gur qrfgvangvba. I just really hope you get the answer, now, 'cause you've seemed to be trying a lot :P

Comment: @user477343 yes I've been thinking this one over a lot I really liked the riddle :p. last thing I can come up with is rot13(ubfcvgny) otherwise I think I will have to leave it to someone else because my vocabulary might not be broad enough since my English isn't that good.

Comment: Well, sir, you have just got the answer. Add an E to each the prefix, infix and suffix; match 'em up with the riddle; and you're good to go! :D

Comment: @user477343 I made an edit to my answer, I actually feel retarded for this because it was the first thing that I had in mind, but since my English isn't good I had no idea of the word hose neither of the word tale (I always just called it stories :p).

Comment: Yay, you got it! It is all correct now! When would you like the tick? :D

Comment: @user477343 doesn't matter see when you're able to :p  just happy that I finally found it :D

Comment: Well, congratulations! Glad you are happy! :D $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Hospital?

My prefix will pray with an S,

> A HOSE is used to S+PRAY, minus the E gives HOS.

My suffix is red with an A,

> A TALE is often RE + A + D, minus the E gives TAL.

My infix, so ill with an F,

> One can definitely be F+ILLed with SPITE, minus the E gives SPIT.

If only affixed with an E.

> So we need to remove the E’s from each of the above words.

Because the answer is SAFE.

> A HOS + SPIT + TAL = HOSPITAL is definitely SAFE!

Comment: a few minutes to late watch my final answer I finally got it after not being retarded anymore and actually looking up words in a dictionary whether they existed or not :p.

Comment: Oh... you got it too. @mrdeadsven, I did not see this answer, but it was answered $5$ minutes ago... ermm.. which one do I tick now??

Comment: @user477343 you can tick this one if you like, mine is kinda a train wreck :p after all the comments and tries

Comment: LOL I didn’t see his answer, but he does have it correct! It’s up to you, @user477343. Happy either way! :D Great puzzle!

Comment: @mrdeadsven I will tick yours, because you really tried and I think you deserve it. And since this answer is the same and is less of a "train wreck" (as you put it), I will give it a $50$ rep bounty. It also has not received as many upvotes as your answer, so I think this is fair. Do you think this is fair?

Comment: El-Guest, read my above comment. Do you think it is fair?

Comment: That works for me, @user477343!

Comment: Okay. Glad it works out :P

Comment: @user477343 All good for me!

Comment: Congratulations! $\boxed{\color{blue}{+50}}$